# Checklist of steps to secure asp.net web application?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, security

I would like to secure an ASP.NET web application against hacking. Is there a list of ASP.NET specific tasks specifically coding wise to make an ASP.NET more secure? Beyond what is mentioned on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998367.aspx). I am interested in specific steps with code examples on ways to avoid cross site request forgeries & cross site scripting.

I know about using SQL parameters for sql injection, Windows authentication when connecting to SQL Server and validating form's input on the server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Microsoft-
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998249.aspx

A more detailed checklist-
http://technotes.towardsjob.com/dotnet/asp-net-developers-checklist-security-checklist/

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx is another good resource for xss protection. The library provides a higher level of protection than the default encoder functionality.

Comment: The second link is broken.  Here is an archived copy of the page: https://web.archive.org/web/20091006040147/http://technotes.towardsjob.com/dotnet/asp-net-developers-checklist-security-checklist

Answer (score 2):

[Top Ten Security Threads](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10)
[How To: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx)
[How To: Protect From Injection Attacks in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355989.aspx)
[How To: Protect From SQL Injection in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998271.aspx)
[How To: Use Regular Expressions to Constrain Input in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998267.aspx)

After I reading above articles,
I summarized way of preventions by using asp.net technologies, and Entity Framework.

**Injection Compliance**
    -Enable Asp.net request validation in asp.net web config file.
    -Turn on custom error mode in asp.net web config file.
    -Use server-side input validation controls to constrain inputs.
    -Validate length, range, format and type for every inputs to system.
    -Use strong data typing.
    -Encode every free-text fields and unsafe output using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode.
    -Validate file paths using System.IO.Path.GetFileName and System.IO.Path.GetFullPath.
    -Use Request.MapPath to map a supplied virtual path to a physical path on the server.
    -Prevent SQL injection attack by using Linq to Entities query syntax.

**Broken Authentication and Session Management Compliance**
    -Use salted hash method for user's sensitive data.
    -Use SSL/TLS protocol for every credentials data.
    -Defined session timeout properly.

**Cross-Site Scripting (XSS) Compliance**
    -Use regular expressions to constrain critical input fields in ASP.NET.
    -Use ASP.net RegularExpressionValidator and RangeValidator to constrain server side input controls.
    -Encode every inputs from the user or from other sources such as databases.

**Insecure Direct Object References Compliance**
    -Give only specific user/group access your project and its related folders.

**Security Misconfiguration Compliance**
    -Show only custom error message to user.

**Sensitive Data Exposure Compliance**
    -Use modern cryptographic algorithms to encrypt all sensitive data.

**Missing Function Level Access Control Compliance**
    -Make sure that your system menu and program list are populated based on user authorization level.
    -Make sure that your system check before response to user request if it is valid for him\her.

**Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF) Compliance**
    -Use CAPTCHA Image to ensure that the request is not generated by a computer.
-Use [CSRF Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc/14473764#14473764) to ensure that the specific page which sent request(s) to your sever is created only by your server.

**Using Known Vulnerable Components Compliance**
    -Always keep components/libraries update.

**Unvalidated Redirects and Forwards Compliance**
    -Make sure that your system always check if URL and its parameters are valid or not, before it is redirected.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/10-steps-to-secure-software?utm_source=Top%205&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=top5%202015-12-18

Answer (score 1):

The OWASP (Open Web Application Security Project) have a convenient list of the top 10 Web Application vulnerabilities:
http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2007

Here is a Microsoft Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library 1.5 tutorial:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa973813.aspx

Here's a very informative, although not very well-known security resource, the ASP.NET 2.0 Internet Secure Reference Implementation - basically Patterns & Practices:
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ASPNETv2RefImp

Last but not least, here's a video on the Architecture Behind CAT.NET:
http://channel9.msdn.com/posts/Jossie/Architecture-behind-CATNET/

Download the latest build of the CAT.NET tool here (32 and 64 bit):
http://bit.ly/164BlV