# The required anti-forgery form field __RequestVerificationToken is not present

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, knockout.js, knockout-mvc, asp.net-mvc-ajax

Could you please help me to solve this issue? I'm implementing sign in form without form or html.beginform because I'm calling the controller /API through Ajax call and based on the status message / success, I want to redirect to some page as per the requirement. Please note, I shouldn't skip the anti-forgery method which has been implemented for the controller method. Thanks.

But I'm not able to proceed further because of "The required anti-forgery form field __RequestVerificationToken is not present"

My View is as follows :

```
""<input data-bind="value: UserName" type="text" name="username" />
  <button type="button" data-bind="click:LoginMethod"> Login       </button>""
```

And the Ajax code is as follows

```
 self.LoginMethod = function () {

        //Ajax call to Insert the Customer record

        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",

            url: "http://localhost:8089/Home/SignIn/",

            data: ko.toJSON(CustData), //Convert the Observable Data into JSON



            success: function (data) {
                console.log("success");
                alert("Record Added Successfully");

            },

            error: function () {
                console.log("failed");
                alert("Failed");

            }

        });
```

Appreciated your's help.

Comment: you have ``ValidateAntiFrogeryToken`` Attribute on your action thats why this error is coming

Comment: Out of the box, the `AntiForgery` feature of MVC only works on traditional form posts. To get it to also work with ajax, the feature needs to be extended. There are a number of good blog posts with examples on how to do this that can be used as a foundation for your own implementation. [Here](http://richiban.wordpress.com/2013/02/06/validating-net-mvc-4-anti-forgery-tokens-in-ajax-requests/) and [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/10/preventing-csrf-with-ajax.aspx/) are good starting points.

Comment: possible duplicate of [include antiforgerytoken in ajax post ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 0):

Change data: ko.toJSON(CustData) to data: ko.toJS(CustData).
And you should be good to go