# MVC use jquery instead of submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, forms

On my page I have a section like this:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("AddSubTor", "Maintor", FormMethod.Post, htmlAttributes: new { ID = "frmSubTors" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

  @Html.Partial("_SublistPartial")

  <div class="row" style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center ">
      @* submit button here *@
      <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Add"  />
    </div>
  </div>
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
```

Instead of using the submit button, I would replace it then with an image that looks like a button, could I also do the same submit in a jquery function. Like in the click event of that button-like image? Would the data I'm submitting still be submitted?

The reason I want to do this is that in the partial I have two radio buttons. On both I have some Jquery code for retrieving data and other stuff.

If I use a simple submit button I can set the radiobuttons but there is no click event thus the data is not retrieved and other stuff is not done.
So if I can use Jquery, then I can simple call the functions that the radiobutton-click events call and so get my data.

[edit]
I'm kind of looking for something like this:

```
$.Ajax({
  url: 'controller/action',
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data) {
    $('#frmSubTors').html(data);
  }
}).done(function() {
  // do my other stuff here
});
```

Would this work too?

Comment: I don't follow your reasoning. A `type="submit"` button doesn't require a `onclick` event, it will post the form values to your action. You last paragraph is kind of vague.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use jQuery to submit the form when the image is clicked.
Replace the submit button with the image and give it an id.

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 text-center ">
      @* submit button here *@
      <img id="myImage" src="blah.jpg" />
</div>
```

Then have jQuery respond to a click event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#myImage").click(function() {
        $("#frmSubTors").submit();
    }
}
```

More click event info for jQuery: http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_click.asp

Comment: But can I do any functions after the submit has finished and the partial is updated? Like with .Ajax you have a Done event that is fired after the data is returned, and then the Jquery script continues. Is that possible here too?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, If you use `$('#frmSubTors').submit()`, The form will be submitted wit all the fields.

Answer (score 1):

You could submit the form using your image event.

```
$('img').on("click", function () {
    $('#frmSubTors').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can submit `form` with ajax like following.

```
$("#your_img_id").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Maintor/AddSubTor',
        data: $(this).serialize(), //serializes the form's elements.
        success: function (data) {
            // do your other stuff here after succesful form submit
        }
    });
});
```

If your `form` has `<input type="file">` then do like following.

```
$("#your_img_id").click(function () {
    var formData = new FormData($('#frmSubTors')[0]);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Maintor/AddSubTor',
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processType: false,
        success: function(data) {
            // do your other stuff here after succesful form submit
        }
   });
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. This did help me a bit. The formdata needs to be serialized, but then I got a new issue, the anti-forgery token thing. Found a solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc