# AntiforgeryToken Not Recognized In Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, csrf, antiforgerytoken

I have a scenario where i dont need to send form data but some other data through ajax call. I have a form which contains `html.AntiForgeryToken()` .

This is what i tried.

```
var modid = $("#moduleList").val();
var data = {};
data.modid = modid;

var token = $('#frmmmenu input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
data.__RequestVerificationToken = token;
//var dataWithToken = $.extend(data, token);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home/MainMenu",
    data: JSON.stringify(data),
    //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  // request data type
    dataType: "html",  // response data type
    success: function (msg) {

        $("#accordion").html(msg);
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("Ajax Error");
    },
});
```

But i keep getting  `The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present`. error.

Here is the Firebug Screen grab

[image]

Also My action method is decorated with ValidateAntiForgeryToken

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult MainMenu(int modid)
{
}
```

What is causing this ? Any Ideas ?

**EDIT** :
This is a MVC5 Project.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Same value as in firebug post.

Comment: Take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc) answer.

Comment: The `ValidationAntiForgeryTokeAttribute` does not support the token coming from JSON.  Kayess's answer does not encode the values as JSON, that answer uses Form Encoded value.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Exactly ! In my case i was not serialising the form and creating the object from scratch. Old habit of sending JSON led to the error :(

Comment: I only use JSON, so I derived from the attribute and wrote my own.  That standard URL encoding pretty much sucks unless you're doing very basic things.

Comment: @ErikPhilips Have you posted your solution anywhere ?

Comment: Sorry I misspoke, I use headers to append the AFT.  I can't post the specific code for this.  But if you wanted to do it, first I would look at [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Mvc/ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute.cs) build your own to pull the valies then call [AntiForgery.Validate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj158363(v=vs.111).aspx).  And for reference: [AntiForgeryWorker](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.WebPages/Helpers/AntiXsrf/AntiForgeryWorker.cs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution.

The culprit was

```
data: JSON.stringify(data),
```

Changed the above to

```
data: data,
```

Now Firebug shows

[image]

Hope somebody can post a solution with JSON as Url length is limited although it requires contentType `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Thank you all for your support.

Comment: Current solution is fine: URL Length is limited, but you're NOT using the URL when you POST via jQuey AJAX. You may be using "url-encoded" content, but that just means it follows the same structure as URL encoding (as opposed to JSON, CSV or something else). It's still being included in the message body, not URL.

Comment: @binderbound Thanks Never new that.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to try every post out there before I made a solution that was working:

**JS**

```
var form = jQuery("#AuthForm");
form.children("input[name=provider]").val(source.SourceName);
form.children("input[name=returnUrl]").val(window.location.href);

$.ajax({
 url: form.attr('action'),
 data: form.serialize(),
 success: function (response) {
  console.log(response);
 }
});
```

*Obviously the values(.val() statements) I'm filling in are specific to my case. Also, I am running this in an angular app.*

**CSHTML**

```
<form id="AuthForm" action="@Url.Action("LinkExternalLogin","LoginInfo")" method="post">
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <input type="hidden" name="provider" value="" />
 <input type="submit" name="returnUrl" value="" />
</form>
```