# POSTing complex JSON to ASP.NET Core Controller

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I have the following models in my ASP.NET Core code:

```
public class TestItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<TestSubItem> SubItems { get; set; }
}

public class TestSubItem
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

and the following method in my Controllers/TestController.cs:

```
    // POST: Test/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public IActionResult Create([FromBody]TestItem item)
    {
        // Use item here...
        return View(item);
    }
```

I have the following JavaScript in my page:

```
var mySubItems = [{"Id": "1"}];

function submitForm() {
    // myForm contains an Id textbox and a Name textbox
    $("#myForm").submit();
};

function doPost() {

    var testItem = {
        Id: "2",
        Name: "testName",
        SubItems: mySubItems
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("Create" ,"Test")',
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(testItem),
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            var x = error; //break here for debugging.
        }
    });
};
```

When I use `doPost`, I always get `400 Bad Request` back from the server. `submitForm` on the other hand works fine, but I don't know how to include `mySubItems` in the data sent to the server.

What's the quickest way out of this?

Comment: `url: '@Url.Action("Create" ,"Test")',`. Are you sure that this works?

Comment: Yes, the url is ok

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Including [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] on your controller is causing the problem. You need to include the token when you post the data. MVC automatically includes it the form which is why submitForm() works.

The challenge is that I do not know how to make it work with JSON data getting posted. You might be able to by adding the following into testItem:

```
__RequestVerificationToken: $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val()
```

For more information, check out [include antiforgerytoken in ajax post ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc)