# CSRF issue in Form.method (asp.net SPA)

Tags: asp.net, csrf, csrf-protection, fortify

I am getting CSRF issue when scanned with HP fortify .

```
jQuery.fn.downloadContentUsingServerEcho = function (fileName, contentType, contentEncoding, content) {
        //// test
        //$.ajax({
        //    type: 'POST',
        //    url: 'download/' + fileName,
        //    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        //    data: JSON.stringify({ contentType: contentType, contentEncoding: contentEncoding, content: content })
        //});

        var form = document.createElement('form');
        form.id = 'downloadForm';
       form.method = 'post';
        form.target = 'downloadTarget';
        form.action = 'download/' + fileName;

        var data = {
            contentType: contentType,
            contentEncoding: contentEncoding,
            content: content
        };

        for (var propName in data) {
            if (!data.hasOwnProperty(propName)) { continue; }
            var propValue = data[propName];
            var input = document.createElement('textarea');
            input.name = propName;
            input.value = propValue;
            form.appendChild(input);
        }

        document.body.appendChild(form);
        form.submit();

        document.body.removeChild(form);
    };
```

I am getting in this    form.method = 'post';

Appreciate your help to fix this issue.

Thanks,

bk

Comment: [Please read and apply](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks).

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how do you prevent against CSRF attacks, OWASP has some good information on it.

[OWASP - Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF)](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_(CSRF))

*Note: It is also hard to read what you are trying to do in your code, you should format it so we can see what you are trying to accomplish.*

Comment: Hello @SBurris .. I have formatted the code . I have checked about CSRF but I am unable to resolve this .

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what your issue is.  If HP fortify is saying that you aren't using a CSRF token to secure your AJAX call then you need to generate a token and pass it up to the server.

For implementation in ASP.NET Microsoft gives a good tutorial on this: https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/xsrfcsrf-prevention-in-aspnet-mvc-and-web-pages

To automatically add the CSRF token to all ajax post calls, you can simply add a prefilter. [include antiforgerytoken in ajax post ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc)

Note: Some frameworks such as Telerik require the CSRF token to be in options.data instead of just the header.