# ASP.NET MVC AJAX POST ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, antiforgerytoken

With my code i get a internal Server error:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "Manage", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form"}))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
}
<script>
function Like(id) {
    var requestData = {
        profileId: id,
        __RequestVerificationToken: $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val(),
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: '/Manage/Like',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function (xhr) { alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText); },
        success: function (result) {},
        async: true,
        processData: false
    });
}
</script>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Like(string profileId)
{ ... }
```

If i remove [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] everything works fine, but i lose the sercurity. How can i fix the internal server error?

I see in fiddler SyntaxView 2 requests:
/Manage/Like
{"profileId":13,"__RequestVerificationToken":"jH2ofYlcTiHl8lixW_ANEHOg5KgwRh5Xl43lQfGkDFh55jX-x5cmz4RfPtbDfu92oQsTM7zsop83ldfbxMdIIELYZ0kfByFcXjUp-5mwyKZcQzjXP2gy6qW0iQOtLsqaDjFSzoxnyqM2MD42CbItzw2"}

/Manage
__RequestVerificationToken=MNiKOJHZg7BGaTNccOjrR2Obf_nPhKfcwIPZVBUl53G368n5euzB4y1htH47VKg3V3mHfxkjYZDz6iPepQ7jpeXGARtlj6vV74B8zQbp4by9JR4Rcz4sHANm3WHb6WAXaLcsnFvWJth_8c98XKda5w2

Comment: Remove the `JSON.stringify`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking this from a sim. question here [include antiforgerytoken in ajax post ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc)

```
function Like(id) {
 var form = $('form');
 var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]', form).val();
 $.ajax({
    url: '/Manage/Like',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { __RequestVerificationToken: token, profileID: id },
    error: function (xhr) { alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText); },
    success: function (result) {},
    async: true,
    processData: false
 }); 
}
```