# Use AntiForgeryToken in ajax - mvc5

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, http, antiforgerytoken

How I can solve this problem:

```
The required anti-forgery form field "__RequestVerificationToken" is not present.
```

I have read a lot of forums but a can't find out a solution. It seems the AntiForgeryToken is not send but I've got not idea how i could do it.

In my view I've include `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()`, my controller has `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`.

```
 var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var url = "..@actionInAPP"
        var token = $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val();
        var params =serialize(document.forms[@numForm]);
        console.log(params);

        http.open("POST", url, true);

           var form_data = new FormData(document.forms[@numForm]);
           return $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: url,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             headers: { '__RequestVerificationToken': token },
             complete: function(){
                http.onreadystatechange = function () {
                     if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                        window.location.reload();
                     }
                     if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 400) {
                        document.getElementById("@targetId").innerHTML = http.responseText;
                     }
                 }
                http.send(params);
            },
          });
```

The information is saved in DB but in my browser I have this 500 error
POST http://localhost:xxxx/xyz/Create 500 (Internal Server Error)

what is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it!!!
i changed the $ajax and it worked perfect

```
return $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url, url,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,
             data: form_data,
             Success: function(){
                http.send(params);
             },
            complete: function(http){
                if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                if (http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 400) {
                    document.getElementById("@targetId").innerHTML = http.responseText;
                }
           }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You may put the `__RequestVerificationToken` in jquery `$ajax.data` field
and,Bring your Form Data in `$ajax.data` field then your Controller will get the form data.

like this

```
  $.ajax({
        url: $(this).data('url'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: { 
            __RequestVerificationToken: token, 
            someValue: 'some value' 
        },
        success: function (result) {
            alert(result.someValue);
        }
    });
```

[include antiforgerytoken in ajax post ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc)