# RequestVerificationToken HttpOnly flag

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to set `HttpOnly=false` for cookie __RequestVerificationToken in Asp.Net MVC? Because I need to read it in javascript and send in request header.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that. You can simply read and post the __RequestVerificationToken to the server by AJAX. Check the following links.

1. [send-and-validate-an-asp-net-antiforgerytoken-as-a-request-header](https://nozzlegear.com/blog/send-and-validate-an-asp-net-antiforgerytoken-as-a-request-header)
2. [include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473597/include-antiforgerytoken-in-ajax-post-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I just want to know if HttpOnly=false is possible and how to do it. Then I will decide if I will use it or not.

Comment: I think it is possible. for example, check this link(https://github.com/aspnet/Antiforgery/issues/29#issuecomment-165304489)

Comment: This link(https://rehansaeed.com/securing-the-aspnet-mvc-web-config/) is useful too. I believe you can find your answer there.